# how to extract rows that contains partially matched strings in all entries of a column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a below dataframe with "Errors" column

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
|student_id|      name|timestamp|Errors  |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
|        s1|  testuser|       t1|E1|E2|E3|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|E2|E4|E5|
|        s2|   test123|       t1|E7|E6|E3|
|        s2| sample123|       t2|E3|E3|E3|
+----------+----------+---------+--------+
```

I want to filter out rows with particular error only (say "E3"). In this example, I wanted the last row alone.

For simplicity, I replaced error messages with "E1, E2 and so on" in this dataframe. But, in real scenario, I will have a long string of error messages concatinated using a delimiter ('|') pipe in this case

Comment: Welcome to SO - please provide a [mcve], which in this case especially means that the dataframe should be easily copy/pastable - not this perhaps nice to read but hard to recreate version.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
err = 'E3'
mask = df.Errors.str.split('|').apply(lambda x: all(e==err for e in x))

df[mask]
#   student_id       name timestamp    Errors
# 3         s2  sample123        t2  E3|E3|E3
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to mask :

```
mask = df['error'].apply(lambda x: True if not re.sub('E3|\|','',x) else False)
```